# Convert bash script to Perl or Python

Tags: python, bash, perl

I have a bash script which greps numeric values from the log files, but it consumes server resources and the server is becoming overloaded. I want to write the same script in Perl or Python. The log file size is approx 1GB and the script needs to run on a daily basis.

```bash
while read  i
do
egrep -h $i  /opt/logs/oc-resizer.log  >> /opt/logs/purge-resizer.tmp
done  < /opt/nasa/shahid/logo.csv
```

Comment: Why would rewriting in python/perl reduce the resource usage?

Comment: bash is slow processing and it takes time to complete the whole process, as per my assumption perl is good/fast for text processing. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I don't see a question there. Are you expecting us to write this for you?

Comment: Just let me know if it is possible with perl? if some one provide me code so it would be great.

Comment: Yes it's possible in perl. No we're not going to write it for you.

Comment: ok thank you for your time.

Comment: @MuhammadShahid Could you include sample regular expressions used in egrep commands?  Quite likely the best approach may be to combine all regular expression into single one and keep using egrep. IMHO Perl is not good for "simplistic" processing of HUGE (1GB) files.

Comment: Hi Andrzej,

I am not using regular expressions in the script, I just need to search ID in oc-resizer.log file in loop, ie "1031210084" ID is included in logo.csv file while loop search 1031210084 in oc-resizer.log file and redirect result into purge-resizer.tmp file.

Comment: @Andrzej, I am also looking way to use multiple strings search via grep instead of while loop.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: I'm interested in what you mean by *simplistic processing* and why you think Perl isn'tgood for it. I wouldn't call a 1GB file *huge*

Comment: @Borodin I remember relative "slowness" of my perl `while(<...>) {` scripts compared to grep speed.  AFAIR I tested it **a few years ago** on a few MB files. I suspect it was mostly due to "unoptimized" file buffering. I am *sure* perl can do *much* better.

Comment: @MuhammadShahid see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31637639/2139766

Comment: @Borodin It was comp with "not too much" memory (lousy in memory file buffers). I have rechecked it again (30MB file, comp with more memory)  -> grep 9ms, perl 15ms. Even if my assumption stands it would require MUCH bigger (text) files.

Answer (score 2):

Just reduce your script to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
egrep -f /opt/nasa/shahid/logo.csv /opt/logs/oc-resizer.log \
              >> /opt/logs/purge-resizer.tmp
```

It will be a lot faster. It will be even faster – if you are searching fixed strings and not patterns – using fgrep instead of egrep:

```
fgrep -f /opt/nasa/shahid/logo.csv /opt/logs/oc-resizer.log \
              >> /opt/logs/purge-resizer.tmp
```

See `man grep` for details.

I don't think that perl or python can get faster that this.